# How to implement Stack using Char as argument?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I have this assignment where I have to implement a stack to work with the following struct given by my professor. As you know I don't know how to implement a stack using the following struct.

```
struct elements{
     char word;
     struct elements *next;
}
```

I do know how to do that using the struct below...

```
struct elements{
     struct student data;
     struct elements *next;
}
```

To insert the data into the stack I'd use... I know dat the code below is correct. I do understand what is happening there. But I cannot see how I can do that using `char word` instead of          `struct student data;` Someone could explain it to me? I'm not getting the idea.

```
int pushStack(Stack* ptr, struct student info){
    Elemn* node = (Elemn*)malloc(sizeof(Elemn);

    if(node == NULL && ptr == NULL){
    printf("error.");
    return 0;
    }

    node->student = info;
    node->next = (*ptr);
    *ptr = node;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why one character is named as word (char word;)?:)

Comment: @tadman In the function declaration there is already used a pointer to pointer Stack* ptr For example consider the statement *ptr = node;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If `Stack` itself is a pointer type that's really obnoxious. Types should be more explicit about their nature.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's part of the assigment. I have to deal with that char. I'm suppose the make the code work using char instead of struct student data; But I have no idea how to do so...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace `struct student` by `char`?
Of course in the function header, but also in the `Elemn` class.